# What does this PROMPT_COMMAND do?

Tags: linux, bash, command-prompt

I have this in `/etc/bash.bashrc` on my Linux system:

`PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'`

From man bash I understand that it sets a command to be executed prior to issuing each prompt, but I'm wondering what exactly it's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it updates the title of the terminal after every command you issue to reflect the current values of the envariables, using XTerm escape sequences.

Some of the escape sequences recognized by XTerm-compatible terminal emulators:

```
ESC]0;stringBEL — Set icon name and window title to string
ESC]1;stringBEL — Set icon name to string
ESC]2;stringBEL — Set window title to string
```

where `ESC` is the escape character (`\033`), and `BEL` is the bell character (`\007`).

Answer (score 1):

Sets your prompt to be whatever is being executed now in addition to a `printf` that will show your username @ your hostname with your present working directory.  You'll have to look up the `\033]0;` terminal code yourself.